# How to solve thisrecurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$f(n)=\frac{1+f(n-1)}{f(n-2)}$
$f(0)=a$
$f(1)=b$
I can't figure out how to solve this. If you multiply both parts by $f(n-2)$, you get
$f(n)f(n-2)-f(n-1)-1=0$,
and I don’t understand how to make a characteristic equation from this (I don’t understand, what to do with $f(n)f(n-2)$).

Comment: Have you calculated the first few terms? Maybe a general form will reveal itself

Comment: @FShrike $f(2)=\frac{1+b}{a}$, $f(3)=\frac{1+a+b}{ab}$, $f(4)=\frac{1+a}{b}$, $f(5)=a$, $f(6)=b$, $f(7)=\frac{1+b}{a}$. But what does it mean?

Comment: Well you have just solved the entire function... it repeats the pattern

Comment: This is an (in)famous [Somos sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence).  There is a general theory of when this sort of miracle can occur, but the "plug-and-chug" techniques of finding a characteristic equation do not apply here.